# Java EE 6 on Glassfish 3.1 CallbackHandler throws NullPointerException

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, jaas

I implemented an own LoginModule for a custom authentication process due to the need for find granular access control. The LoginModule looks like that:

```
public class PasswordSafeLoginModule implements LoginModule {

    private Subject subject;
    private CallbackHandler callbackHandler;
    private Object sharedState;
    private Object options;

    private Set<Principal> principalsAdded;
    private boolean authenticated;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
            Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.callbackHandler = callbackHandler;
        this.sharedState = sharedState;
        this.options = options;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
        // TODO
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
        // TODO
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login() throws LoginException {
        NameCallback nameCB = new NameCallback("Username");
        PasswordCallback passwordCB = new PasswordCallback("Password", true);
        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[] { nameCB, passwordCB };
        try {
            callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
            // Authenticate username/password
            username = nameCB.getName();
            password = String.valueOf(passwordCB.getPassword());
            //
            // lookup credentials
            //
            // TODO...
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
            throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
        logger.info("Logging out '" + username + "'...");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I add this LoginModule configuration with a @Singleton bean on @Startup:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class PasswordSafeJAASConfiguration extends Configuration {

    /**
     * This method just registers the configuration after the construction.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        Configuration.setConfiguration(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(
            String applicationName) {
        AppConfigurationEntry[] entries = new AppConfigurationEntry[1];
        entries[0] = new AppConfigurationEntry(
                PasswordSafeLoginModule.class.getName(),
                LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, new HashMap<String, Object>());
        return entries;
    }
}
```

The login shall be form based on an own JSF 2.0 page. I put everything into a composite:implementation for later reuse. The relevant part look like:

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
    <h:messages />
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="rightAlign,leftAlign">
        <h:outputText value="Email address:" />
        <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" size="8">
            <f:validator validatorId="emailAddressValidator" />
            <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="128" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="Password:" />
        <h:inputText id="j_password" required="true" size="8" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="Login..." />
</form>
```

When I try to test everything, I see in the logs (logging removed from the code above) that the configuration was added and that my own login module was started (initialize and login). But as soon as the CallbackHandler is started the callback handler throws a NullPointerException:

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.ServerLoginCallbackHandler.handle(ServerLoginCallbackHandler.java:109)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler$1.run(LoginContext.java:955)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler.handle(LoginContext.java:951)
    at com.puresol.passwordsafe.jaas.PasswordSafeLoginModule.login(PasswordSafeLoginModule.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[...]
```

What is happening here? Why is there a NullPointerException? I expect, that the CallbackHandler I get is from the underlying JAAS implementation and gives me the provided username and password back. Why is this not happening?

I tried an alternative way. I let the JSF form put the username and password into a @ManagedBean and called the login procedure via HttpServletRequest:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
        .getExternalContext().getRequest();
request.login(login.getEmail(), login.getPassword());
```

When I do this, I get an NullPointerException, too:

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.ServerLoginCallbackHandler.handle(ServerLoginCallbackHandler.java:109)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler$1.run(LoginContext.java:955)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler.handle(LoginContext.java:951)
    at com.puresol.passwordsafe.jaas.PasswordSafeLoginModule.login(PasswordSafeLoginModule.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[...]
```

My own LoginModule was called again and again the ServerLoginCallbackHandler throws a NullPointerException at the same position. Ok, that's reproducable and repeatable. But, in this variant I checked, that non-null values were put into login() for username and password.

Where can I look now? What is the issue? Any glue will help. I puzzle on this issue for three days now and the web is not providing useful information on that. At least with the key words, I use...

Comment: Why haven't you implemented CallbackHandler or did you?

Comment: I think, I do not need it!? I am not sure, but I use the j_security_check servlet and I think the provided callback handler in LoginModule.initialize(...) is from this underlying implementation and I can retrieve the information about password and username that way. Is'n it right? The documentation I read is not very specific about the callback handlers...

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. All but one of the examples I looked at had the CallbackHandler implemented. It also seemed they were doing a real minimal implementation. It doesn't look like it would take long to try out. Maybe, give it a shot?

Comment: Yes, sure. I can try. What do you have? I work with the Java EE Tutorial (very confusing), Java EE 6 on Glassfish and JSF 2.0 Cookbook by PacktPub and several tutorials/examples I could find. But none of them tells explicitly what and how to do it. The LoginModules are described in detail and also how to setup JSF or JSP to ask for username and password and also how to configure web.xml and sun-web.xml.

Comment: Go here http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2008/04/authentication-using-JAAS.html and look at the post, then grab the example code. It has what you need.

Comment: This is not helping at all. The sample code is for JDK standalone and not for Java EE. I did something like that before and it worked quite well. I have issues with the underlaying process in Java EE. :-(

Comment: Hmmm... you're right. Maybe this will help http://www.java.net/external?url=http://blogs.sun.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/adding_authentication_mechanisms_to_the

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4246/discussion-between-preston-and-rick-rainer-ludwig)